# If $aH$ generates $G/H$ where $G$ is cyclic, then $a$ generates $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group, finitely-generated

When $G$ is a cyclic group, any subgroup $H$ of it is also cyclic and hence the quotient group $G/H$ is also cyclic. Moreover, if $a\in G\setminus H$ be a generator of $G$ then $\langle aH\rangle$ is a generator of $G/H$. While I was studying the proof I, I was curious to know the converse part in a special case.

Suppose $G$ is a finite cyclic group and $G/H$ is cyclic with $aH$ as one of its generators where $a\in G\setminus H$. Can we say $a$ is a generator of $G$ as well?

I know that there are plenty non-cyclic groups possessing cyclic quotient groups(for example $S_3$ is non-cyclic and $S_3/A_3$ is cyclic), but if it is stated beforehand that $G$ is cyclic, I don't know how to proceed.

I was hoping to find a counter-example but in vain. Neither I was convinced that the statement is false. Any help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be cyclic of order $6$, written multiplicatively and generated by $x$. Let $H$ be generated by $x^3$. Then $H$ has two elements, and $G/H$ has three elements. Since $G/H$ is cyclic of prime order, any nontrivial element generates it. Therefore, $x^2H$ is a generator of $G/H$.

But $x^2$ has order $3$ in $G$, so $x^2$ does *not* generate $G$.

This is the smallest counterexample possible (unless you allow $H=G$, which are you implicitly but not explicitly excluding): you cannot have a counterexample if $G$ has prime order (since in that case $H$ must be either trivial or the whole thing). And for the cyclic group of order $4$, all elements that do not lie in the nontrivial proper subgroup generate the whole group. So the smallest order where a counterexample was possible was $6$, and there it is.

Comment: Beautifully explained and cleared my doubt. I have a question. As you stated, if $G$ has prime order, we cannot have counter example. What is order of $G$ is some odd prime-powered ? Can it work?

Comment: @KON3 For order $p^2$, the same thing happens as with order $4$: any element not in the subgroup of order $p$ is a generator. For any prime, even or odd, the subgroups of the cyclic group of order $p^n$ are totally ordered, so any element whose image generates $G/H$ (provided $H\neq G$) will generate $G$.

Comment: Cool. That means, for example if $|G|=p^5$ and $G/H$ is of order $p$ generated by $aH$ say, then $a$ generates $G$, am I right ? If so, I am willing to prove it. Can you show some idea please ?

Comment: @KON3 I already did: the subgroups are totally ordered by inclusion, so the correspondence guarantees it.